# How to keep track of users by identifier using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, chat

I am listening to a small socket.io chat application. Every time a user joins, the server emits a message with the user's name and an id generated on the spot. However, when the user sends a message, the server only broadcasts the message with the userid, and without the username. This snippet of code shows the events that are triggered when a user connects and sends a message.

```
    socket.on('chat_new_user', (data) => {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log('new user!')
        console.log(json.userid)
        console.log(json.username)

    });
    socket.on('chat_new_message', (data) => {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(`${json.userid} - new message!`)
        console.log(json.msg)
```

My issue is, how can I log the user's name to my console when he sends a new message, even though I only have the userID in the message json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to store the users data in an array

```js
    const users = []
    
    socket.on('chat_new_user', (data) => {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log('new user!')
        console.log(json.userid)
        console.log(json.username)
        users.push({ id: json.userid, username: json.username })
    });
    socket.on('chat_new_message', (data) => {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(`${json.userid} - new message!`)
        const user = users.find((user) => user.id === json.userid)
        console.log(json.msg)
        // check whether `user` exit
        if (user) {
           console.log(user.username)
        }
```